# JSONModel - Key is a number, can I get the children by offset?

Tags: objective-c, json, jsonmodel

How do I parse this JSON in Objective C? I've been using jsonmodel.com's code to parse.

```
    {
   "found":10958,
   "start":3141,
   "hits":[
      {
         "pid":"76493",
         "title":"Beton Armu00e9",
         "artist":"Raiden",
         "genre":"Dubstep",
         "image":"A76493_BetonArm_BetonArm.jpg",
         "label":"Offkey",
         "year":"2011",
         "price":9.99,
         "release":"Beton Armu00e9",
         "type":"Album",
         "tracks":{
            "0":{
               "name":"Barbican",
               "file":"A76481_Barbican.mp3",
               "tracknum":1,
               "pid":"76481"
            },
            "1":{
               "name":"Trinity",
               "file":"A76482_Trinity.mp3",
               "tracknum":2,
               "pid":"76482"
            },
            "2":{
               "name":"Tricorn",
               "file":"A76483_Tricorn.mp3",
               "tracknum":3,
               "pid":"76483"
            },
            "3":{
               "name":"Brutalist",
               "file":"A76484_Brutalist.mp3",
               "tracknum":4,
               "pid":"76484"
            },
            "4":{
               "name":"Trellick",
               "file":"A76485_Trellick.mp3",
               "tracknum":5,
               "pid":"76485"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

JSONModel expects a pointer string to declare the keys, but the keys here are numbers. This is what I need, but won't work:

```
#import "JSONModel.h"
#import "songParentModel.h"

@protocol albumModel @end

@interface albumModel : JSONModel

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *title;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *image;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *artist;
@property (strong,nonatomic) songParentModel *0; // THIS DOESN'T WORK (of course)

@end
```

I just need to get the first track, but it would be nice to know how to get them all.

My best guess for a solution would be to stop using JSONModel and parse the JSON with some other simplified method.

Comment: Well, first off that's not JSON.  Even if parsed into dictionaries and arrays there would be a leading (and very significant) `{` or `(`.

Comment: So one must guess that you've dropped the outermost `{` and have a dictionary of dictionaries of dictionaries.  The outer dictionary has only the one element "tracks", which is a dictionary, and it contains elements named "0", "1", "2"... which are also dictionaries.  They contain elements named "file", "name", "pid", "tracknum".  So reference one dictionary at a time until you've peeled enough layers of the onion to get to the data you want.

Comment: Sorry, in my first draft of this question, I pasted the output from xCode of the parsed JSON. That was a mistake. I've replaced it with the a snippet of the actual JSON.

Comment: Hot Licks: I understand how to use it for keys that are more than just a number, but the problem is that I can't create a pointer named *0, so how do I specify the first child?

Comment: Why do you need to create a pointer named *0?  You don't have to fetch dictionary entries into variables whose names match the keys.  Just fetch into "trackData", or, if you must, "track0".

Comment: `NSDictionary* tracks = jsonDict[@"tracks"];  NSDictionary* currentTrack = tracks[@"0"]; NSString* trackName = currentTrack[@"name"];`

Comment: But of course, now that you've shown the full JSON there's another dictionary and an array to traverse. `NSArray* hits = jsonDict[@"hits"]; NSDictionary* hit = hits[0]; NSDictionary* tracks = hits[@"tracks];...`

Comment: The keys in your JSON are not numbers, they are strings. (That's why they are in quotes)

Answer (score -1):

Create a class like this :

The header:

```
#import "JSONModel.h"

@protocol Track @end

@interface Track : JSONModel

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* name;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSString* file;
@property (assign, nonatomic) int tracknum;
@property (strong, nonatomic) int pid;

@end
```

Leave the implementation as default.
now in your model add this property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray<Track>* allTracks;
```

And also change the implementation for `+(JSONKeyMapper*)keyMapper` and add the below item to your dictionary.

```
+(JSONKeyMapper*)keyMapper
{
return [[JSONKeyMapper alloc] initWithDictionary:@{
        @"tracks":@"allTracks",
        }];
}
```

In this way you get an array of all the tracks and you can also get all the details for each track as well.

Comment: How does this handle the fact that each track is inside a parent labeled with it's track number? "allTracks" is not the key, the key is the number zero (0).

When I tried your code, I got this obvious error: "Incoming data was invalid [albumModel initWithDictionary:]. Keys missing: {(
    allTracks
)}"

Comment: How do you initialize your model? I think there is a problem with the way you initialize your model. 
e.g Check out this link: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=hello&max-results=50&alt=json
Here 'entry' is like your 'tracks' the way I parse this json and get all the entry was to initialize my model like this:
    self.videosArray = [VideoModel arrayOfModelsFromDictionaries:json[@"feed"][@"entry"]
    ];
and then loop through all my VideoModel. I can show you the exact implementation of my VideoModel if you think this approach will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I bailed on the JSONModel lib. I think you may have missed the crucial issue I was having. None of your replies actually address the issue.